# Fetch data from a column using SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I want the most suitable query to fetch data in selected column from SQLite database between two dates (the date format will be `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm`).

Comment: what is the column data type in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
select *
from your_table
where the_time between $d1 and $d2
```

Where `$d1` and `$d2` are the end points of your date range in YYYY-MM-DD format.